# free() function only frees the first element of a struct?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I'm working with two structs:

```
typedef struct ListNode{
    void* value;
    struct ListNode *next;
    struct ListNode *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct List{
    Node *first;
    Node *last;
    int count;
} List;
```

Then i declare these variable and allocate memory

```
List *x = calloc(1,sizeof(List));
Node *x1 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
Node *x2 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
x->first = x1;
x->last =x2;
x->count = 2;
free(x);
```

So i'm pretty sure that if i free `x`, the `x->count`, `x->first`, `x->last` will also disappear as well. However, in this case ,i use gdb to check, and surprisingly only the first element of x is removed (e.g: if in the struct `List` i put count on the top, then it will remove only count and leave the rest intact). Why is this happening, and how do i `free()` the whole struct?

Comment: *"So i'm pretty sure that if i free x, the x->count,x->first,x->last will also disappear as well."* The whole object is freed and as such, the pointer `first` that is part of the object disappears. However, the object that the pointer points to doesn't. For that you would have to call `free(x->first);` beforehand.

Comment: well i know that my example are incomplete, but the point here is the pointer "last" doesnt disappear as well as the "count".

Comment: The pointer `last` disappears as well as the `count` integer. Anyway, the content stored to that memory address will be still in memory, unreachable unless you saved a copy of the pointer somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean with "disappear"? The memoys location still exists. The memory cells are not removed from your hardware. ;) The values are not changed as well. You are simply not allowed to access any of those memory locations after calling `free`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. If you do `free(x)` you're only freeing the block of memory holding the contents of `x`, but since **this block contains some pointers to other blocks**, you will need to `free()` those first. This is because `free()` does not care about the content of the memory you're freeing, it doesn't do anything fancy. If you see some value modified after using `free()`, it's just because `free()` uses that memory to store some useful internal values to keep track of memory usage, and it's only a coincidence if that happens to "clear" a pointer in your struct.

The correct way to `free()` your struct is the following:

```
free(x->first);
free(x->last);
// DO NOT free(x->count), it's an integer, not a previously allocated pointer!
free(x);
```

---

Here's a visual representation (pardon my awful handwriting):

[image]

Comment: Nice drawing! ;)

Comment: thanks for being so dedicated! So after i call free(x) i cannot access x->first right?

Comment: @VanTeoLe that's right. If you `free()` something, you cannot access it anymore, since you have no guarantee about the content of that memory block anymore.

Comment: wait let me ask a stupid question. x->first is a pointer and also a part of a struct. If i free(x), then when i try to access x->first, will it let me pass as a mere pointer,(since a pointer is still there) or will it not let me access memory as a member of the struct i freed?

Comment: @VanTeoLe after you free x, you could still do `x->first`, but you would have no guarantee that such pointer is still valid. It could be valid, or it could have been touched by `free()` or something else. It is undefined behavior, and you cannot rely on it. In fact, if you try to compile with address sanitizer (`-O0 -g -fsanitize=address -lasan -fno-omit-frame-pointer`) and run a program that does `free(x); free(x->first);` you will get a giant error and your program will be stopped by asan.

Comment: @smokehill ok i will now

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the memory layout of the struct... i'm no expert so this will be really really simplified:

List x = [pointer-to-x1][pointer-to-x2][int] (plus padding)

So when you run calloc(1, sizeof(List)), you aren't creating the x1 and x2 structs in the same region of memory as the List, because they are just pointers to some other place in memory. you are just creating small reference to them which hasn't even been setup yet. That's why you have to malloc x1 and x2 separately.

so when you free(x), you also aren't freeing x1 or x2 either. free doesn't know how and doesn't know that you ran malloc for x1 and x2. if it tried to free it, it could end up freeing memory too early or freeing memory on the stack. it's only going to look at the region of memory i mapped out above.

Was writing this and saw another answer just come in. Marco has a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have invalid expectation what happens when you call `free`.
You cannot verify the result of `free` in GDB.

Freeing a memory location does not mean that the memory in that place is modified in any way. It may still look the same as before. The OS or C runtime library may set it to all zero, but that's not mandatory. Also the pointer `x` will not change.

Freeing an address only means that you tell the OS it can take it back and give it to someone else.
After calling `free` you are no longer allowed to access the memory.
That's all what happens after `free`.

Therefore `last` and `count` will not "disappear".

That said, you also have a memory leak as others have already pointed. Freeing `x` does not free any other memory accessible via `x->first` or `x->last`.